# Invocar a un formulario desde dos formularios diferentes

Tags: vb.net

Tengo un formulario `FRMBuscarCliente`, el cual lo invoco desde dos formularios diferentes `FrmConsultarEstado` y `FrmRegistroExpediente`.

Desde el formulario `FrmConsultarEstado`  tienen un botón que me lleva al `FRMBuscarCliente` donde busco a un cliente y cuando lo encuentro doy clic y el código y número de documento lo lleva a unas textbox del `FrmConsultarEstado`.

De la misma forma quiero hacer con el formulario `FrmRegistroExpediente`; pero quiero usar el mismo formulario `FRMBuscarCliente`. ¿Cómo hacer para que el `FRMBuscarCliente` sepa a que formulario destino va a llevar la información?

Comment: Seria bueno que colocaras lo que has intentado. (Si, hablo de tu codigo)

Answer (score 1):

Crea una propiedad en el formulario `FRMBuscarCliente` y luego antes de llamar a este formulario asignale el formulario que lo esta invocando. Con esto tendrás la referencia al formulario que lo esta llamando y puedes asignar valores al formulario padre.

```
FRMBuscarCliente.Padre = Me // FrmConsultarEstado y FrmRegistroExpediente
FRMBuscarCliente.Show()
```

Comment: O usar la propiedad `Owner` del formulario de búsqueda, donde puedes asignar a su formulario padre como aprovechar otras propiedades. Revisar `Comentarios` del link https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.form.owner(v=vs.110).aspx